what does "drwxrwxrwx" mean in dired
I'm pretty new to Emacs and haven't used Linux much in the past. So I'm not sure what these strings of text means in Emacs. It's clear that any directory starts with the letter d and a document starts with -, but why is it displayed in the Find File or dired buffer? What does each of these mean?

Is there any documentation which explains this?

this is an ls-related question instead of Emacs

Usually Emacs for Windows uses ls-lisp.el to simulate GNU ls

Not an Emacs question.

I'm a Windows user, using Emacs for Windows. And after reading the response and going through the provided url, I realize now that the question is completely Linux related. But I haven't really seen this anywhere else other than Emacs. I guess Emacs is the only tool I use which is heavily terminal based.

You can make File Explorer display details about files in a directory and add columns with additional information (e.g. size, ownership, attributes). Those are similar to what ls -l provides, but of course, the model of a file is different between Windows and Unix so the information is not quite the same; in particular, the permissions model is different.

Understood, thank you for sharing the details.

These are the rights under Unix in general and Linux in particular.
if you type ls -l in a terminal you will get the same thing.
"drwxrwxrwx" means that it is a directory (d) and is readable, writable and executable (directories must be executable) for root, the owning group and the owner.
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-file-permissions-explained
